# Users with only one role in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, roles

I have an User entity which has its getRoles method. But, to get this work, getRoles() need to return an array, something like:

```
class User implements UserInterface {
    ...
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array($this->roles);
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem comes when I try to make a form to create new users. This is because each user should have only one role, so, I create a field like this:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    ...
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
              'choices' => array(
                  'Role 1' => 'ROLE_ONE',
                  'Role 2' => 'ROLE_TWO',
                  'Role 3' => 'ROLE_THREE',
                  'Role 4' => 'ROLE_FOUR'
                  ),
              'label' => 'Role')
        )
        ...
```

But when I try to render it, it throws me the error: "Notice: Array to string conversion", and this is because with the ChoiceType, I just can select one option. This issue is fixed with the option:

```
'multiple' => true
```

But this allows to select more than one option (what it's not what I want).

I try to return just the role, not an array:

```
class User implements UserInterface {
    ...
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }
    ...
}
```

With this, the form works now, but the login stops working and tells me the next:

> **Catchable Fatal Error**: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct()  must be of the type array, string given...

The logical of my application is that the user has just one role, I don't need an array, but I don't know how to tell to symfony (at the login) that the "roles" is just one (string) not more (array)...

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

> The logical of my application is that the user has just one role

`UserInterface` *require* an array of roles, therefore if you want that your users can only have one of them, you should reflect that logic in your model.

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    protected $role;

    // ...

    public setRole($role)
    {
        if (!is_string($role)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid role');
        }

        $this->role = $role;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array($this->role);
    }

    // ...
}
```

then a

```
->add('role', ChoiceType::class, array(
      'choices' => array(
          'Role 1' => 'ROLE_ONE',
          'Role 2' => 'ROLE_TWO',
          'Role 3' => 'ROLE_THREE',
          'Role 4' => 'ROLE_FOUR'
      ),
      'label' => 'Role'
))
```

is perfectly fine, since `setRole` expects a string, and `getRoles` just wrap and return an array of that value as the interface wants.

Comment: Thank you! but the ChoiceType still gives me the error: `"Notice: Array to string conversion"`. The problem is that getRoles() returns an array...

Comment: you should map `->add('role',`, not `->add('roles',`

Comment: otherwise you can use a [Data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

Unmap the entity field roles with 'mapped' => false:

```
->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'User' => 'ROLE_USER',
            ],
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'Role'
        ]);
```

Then, on the controller, set the user role with the data from the form:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setRoles([$form->get('roles')->getData()]);
```

Hope this helps.